# Typescript - Getting object values with keys - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript

I have an interface for a form values:

```
export interface FormProps {
  name: string
  customerIds: number[]
  primaryColor: string
  headingColor: string
  websiteLink?: string
  websiteLinkEnabled: boolean
  contactLink?: string
  contactLinkEnabled: boolean
  instagramLink?: string
  instagramLinkEnabled: boolean
  facebookLink?: string
  facebookLinkEnabled: boolean
  logo: File[]
  numberOfImages: number
}
```

I would like to check if the fields are dirty, by a function that takes an array of string that maps to each field and then check if there is a difference between the old and new values:

```
const colorsFields = ['primaryColor', 'headingColor']
checkIfFieldsAreDirty(colorsFields, initialValues, values)

const checkIfFieldsAreDirty = (fields: string[], initialValues: FormProps, values: FormProps): boolean => fields.some(field => initialValues[field] !== values[field]
```

But, I get a Typescript error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FormProps'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'FormProps'.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an array of string in order to access elements inside `initialValues`, in order to do this, you have to pass an array of `keyof FormProps`:

```
const colorsFields: (keyof FormProps)[] = ['primaryColor', 'headingColor']
```

An example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)